# How to use LIMIT on LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, orm, eloquent, mariadb, relational-database

I have 2 tables called `categories` and `products` with this relationship:

`categories.category_id` = `products.product_category_id`

I want to show all categories with 2 products of them!

```
[
    [category 1] =>
            [
                'category_id' => 1,
                'category_title' => 'category_title 1',
                [products] => [
                    '0' => [
                            'product_category_id' => 1,
                            'product_id' => 51,
                            'product_title' => 'product_title 1',
                        ],
                    '1' => [
                            'product_category_id' => 1,
                            'product_id' => 55,
                            'product_title' => 'product_title 2',
                        ]
                ]
            ],
    [category 2] =>
            [
                'category_id' => 2,
                'category_title' => 'category_title 2',
                [products] => [
                    '0' => [
                            'product_category_id' => 2,
                            'product_id' => 32,
                            'product_title' => 'product_title 3',
                        ],
                    '1' => [
                            'product_category_id' => 2,
                            'product_id' => 33,
                            'product_title' => 'product_title 4',
                        ]
                ]
            ],
    ...
]
```

I Laravel eloquent I can use something like this:

```
$categories = Category::with(['products' => function($q) {
    $q->limit(2)
}])->get();
```

But I am not using Laravel and I need pure SQL code!
I've tried this code:

```
SELECT
    CT.category_id,
    PT.product_category_id,
    CT.category_title,
    PT.product_id,
    PT.product_title
FROM
    categories CT
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products 
    LIMIT 2
) AS PT
ON
    CT.category_id = PT.product_category_id
WHERE
    CT.category_lang = 'en'
```

But there is a problem with this code! It seems that MYSQL first gets 2 first rows in `products` table and then tries to have a `LEFT JOIN` from `categories` to that 2 rows! and this cause returning `null` values for products (while if I remove `LIMIT` it works great but I need `LIMIT`)

I've tested this code too: (**UPDATED**)

```
SELECT
    CT.category_id,
    PT.product_category_id,
    CT.category_title,
    PT.product_id,
    PT.product_title
FROM
    categories CT
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        product_category_id = CT.category_id
    LIMIT 5
) AS PT
ON
    CT.category_id = PT.product_category_id
WHERE
    CT.category_lang = 'en'
```

But I've received this error:

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'CT.category_id' in 'where clause'

I cant access to `CT.category_id` in the subquery.

what is the best solution?

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?.

Comment: @wchiquito Server type: MariaDB 
Server version: 10.1.29-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution 
Protocol version: 10

Comment: Yeah so the issue is that you cannot reference a column from the base query from a JOIN subquery. I'll remove all my above comments to clean things up, feel free to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you would need to use variables.  The basic idea is:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = product_category_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := product_category_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select p.* 
            from products p
            order by p.product_category_id
           ) p cross join
           (select @c := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) p
where rn <= 2;
```

You can use this as your subquery and then join in the rest of the category information.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46a0985d865fc176dcc471f9457be229) is a db<>fiddle if this code working.

In MySQL 8+/MariaDB 10.2+, this is much more easily written as:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_category_id order by product_category_id) as seqnum
      from products p
     ) p
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Note:  You can specify which 2 products you want (say, the first two alphabetically) by adjusting the `order by` clauses in the two queries.

EDIT:

In MariaDB 10.2, you apparently *cannot* use a subquery for the ordering, so the appropriate query would be:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = product_category_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := product_category_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from products p cross join
           (select @c := -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by p.product_category_id
     ) p
where rn <= 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=93cd4ca8879e19ef5aa7bc5846b5b896) is the db<>fiddle for that.

You can also use this method:

```
select p.*
from products p
where (select count(*)
       from products p2
       where p2.product_category_id = p.product_category_id and p2.id <= p.id
      ) <= 2;
```

I don't really recommend this, because the correlated subquery typically has much worse performance than the `order by`.  But if there are not too many products per category, then this will be fine (with the right indexes).

Comment: When I use the first one I face this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 14

Comment: And when I use the secode one I face this error: select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category_id order by category_id) as seqnum
      from products p
     ) p
where seqnum <= 2;

Comment: @soheilyo The second query requires MariaDB 10.2+.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir mine is: Server version: 10.1.29-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution, What's your idea about the first query?

Comment: @soheilyo . . . There was an extraneous line in the first query.  I've removed it.

Comment: @soheilyo Replace `category_id` with `product_category_id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff   I've run this, but there is no limitation :/ it returns all products

Comment: @soheilyo . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  The code works.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work properly on MariaDB: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=46a0985d865fc176dcc471f9457be229

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir . . . Wow!  I learned something (which I will probably promptly forget).  The ordering in the subquery is required in more recent versions of MySQL and works in earlier versions.  However, it does not work in MariaDB 10.2.  Strange . . . but probably due to extensions to support parallel processing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - According to the Standard, a subquery is "an unordered collection".  MariaDB jumped onto that first; Oracle followed suit.  Parallel processing seems to still be a distant idea (for both forks).  I got burned in MariaDB 5.5 in 2012: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/